Comprehensive List of Shul Customs and Laws Specific to Nusach Sefard
I'm looking for a comprehensive list of shul customs and laws specific to Nusach Sefard. For example, I would like details on the order of tefillos, when one wears a tallis (shliach tzibur and the baal koreh), when they say Kiddush Levanah, when they omit tachanun and any other relevant customs. I have searched the site but have not found a detailed compilation. Could anyone provide a resource or detailed explanation of these customs? Thank you!

Not only would such a list be a full book, but there isn't just one version of nusach sfard but many, each with its own book

See this answer potentially - https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/95591/22152

Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see here for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!
